# C#でシステムサウンドのパスを取得する方法

Tags: c#, windows

お世話になります。
表題の通りなのですが、C#でWindowsのシステムサウンドのパスを取得する方法はありますでしょうか。
「SystemSounds」でパスを取得できないかと考えたのですが、どうもこれでは取得できないようです。
また、そもそも「SystemSounds」は、一部のシステムサウンドしか取得できないため、これ以外のシステムサウンド（「ナビゲーションの開始」等）は利用できないため、困っています。
レジストリからパスを取得できないかと思って、いろいろ調べているのですが、うまい調べ方がわかりませんでした。
何かアドバイスを頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: パスを得ることが目的なのでしょうか？得られたパスを使用して更なる操作を行うことが目的だったりしないのでしょうか？

Comment: はい、パスを得るのが目的です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

レジストリの`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps`下に保存されているようです。ただし、明確に言及されたドキュメントは見つけられなかったため、今後も継続して利用可能かの保証はありません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。そこに保存されていたのですね。大変助かりました。